# ionic slider not working while dynamically updating ionic slider ion-slide-box using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I an using ionic slider to display some data in slides for specific day now when date is updated by user slider needs to changed. But it's not working properly

Slider code:

```
<ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)" class="{{showList}}" does-continue="true" ng-if="todos.today.length">
<ion-slide ng-repeat="todo in todos.today track by $index" >
<div class="list card" >
<ion-checkbox ng-model="todo.did">{{todo.name}}</ion-checkbox>
<label class="item item-input">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="todo.name">
</label>
<label class="item item-input">
<input type="text" placeholder="Description" ng-model="todo.desc">
</label>
<label class="item item-input">
<input type="number" placeholder="Amount" ng-model="todo.amount">
 </label>
 <br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="saveThis(todo)">save</button>
</div>
</ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

my Datepicker

```
    <ionic-datepicker date="currentDate" min="minDate" max="maxDate" callback="datePickerCallback">
  <button class="button   button-block" style="font-size:26px; padding:10px;margin-top:0px; background-color:#009688;color:white"> {{ currentDate.getDate()}} {{month}}</button>
</ionic-datepicker>
```

Controller :

```
$scope.datePickerCallback = function (val) {
    if (!val) {
        console.log('Date not selected');
    } else {

        $scope.sliderChange();
        AppDate.dt=val;
        dao.date=val;
    var tmp={fr:1,did:true,name:'newItm',desc:'',amount:20,date:''};
        $scope.todos.today.push(tmp);
        $scope.month=month_name(dao.date.getMonth(),1);
        $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update();
        console.log("Updated");
    }
}
```

Ionic slider
[image]

after changing date
[image]

Comment: Have you tried wrapping `$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update()` in `$timeout`?

Slidebox has multiple issues when used with ng-repeat, in my case, there were ghost pagers and whenever I updated, slidebox flickered. To solve this I used a $templateCache

Comment: if push elements one by one in controller it's working fine but when i change whole list not in controller but in a service it's not working. How you solve this using $templateCache?

Comment: No, I had another problem. Slidebox flickered everytime I added a new element in the array. So I used custom template instead of directly rendering slidebox.

Comment: Can you make a codepen or plunkr?

Comment: @Lokesh Suthar you can access it [here](https://github.com/codecracker2014/pAccounting)